# One Domain configured with two hosting server

Tags: domains, web-hosting, server, mod-alias

We have Two servers : webserver (Server one) Server (IP: `198.51.100.44`) Mobile server (Server Two) (IP: `203.0.113.88`)

One Domain name : `example.com`

Once anyone opens `https://example.com` open the server one page. if anyone opens `https://example.com/mob` open the server two pages.

We have assigned to server one IP address to Domain A record & we have created a virtual host file server one.

please guide him on how to assign server two dir. the path this link, `https://example.com/mob` via virtual host or.htaccess.

Comment: Would you be wiling to switch from a subdirectory (`example.com/mob`) to a subdomain (`mob.example.com`)?   The latter would be so much easier to set up in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do what you ask the way you asked.

**An IP address is associated with a domain, NOT A URL.**

This means you either need to change example.com/mob to mob.example.com or use a reverse proxy to intercept and reroute requests (which means all traffic will flow via the reverse proxy).  There are lots of different reverse proxy solutions depending on your use case)